# Auth0: fetch data of group of users

Tags: javascript, auth0, dataloader

I have an application with Auth0 and graphQl.

I use dataloaders to batching requests to DB. https://github.com/graphql/dataloader

For example, fetching data from DB looks like:

```
// Booking is Mongoose model
new DataLoader(
  bookingIds => Booking.find({ _id: { $in: bookingIds } }),
);
```

And now I need to fetch data about group of users. Of course, I can write

```
// getUser is ManagementClient.getUser from 'auth0' package
new DataLoader(
  userIds => Promise.all(
    userIds.map(
      id => getUser({ id }),
    ),
  ),
)
```

This solution is slowly. Can I get data of collection of users by one request?

Answer (score 0):

I work with the Auth0 Community team. You can [retrieve users with the GET users endpoint](https://auth0.com/docs/users/search/v3/get-users-endpoint) from the management console. Give it a look when you get a chance. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. But I cant find by id by this endpoint. When I trying, I have an error: Invalid query: filter can not be used with unknown field 'id'